# Eclipse throws NullPointerException while submitting a form

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
    **Edit :**

        package com.example.signup;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class RegistrationPage extends Activity {
        EditText firstname, middlename, lastname, dob, country, username, mailid,password,confirmpassword;
        Button submit_registration_page;
        DBAdapter db;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_page);
            submit_registration_page= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_registration_button);
            submit_registration_page.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (firstname.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                        firstname.setError("Enter your firstname");
                    } else if (middlename.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        middlename.setError("Enter your middlename");
                    } else if (lastname.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        lastname.setError("Enter your lastname");
                    } else if (dob.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        dob.setError("Enter your date of birth");
                    } else if (country.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        country.setError("Enter your habitat");
                    } else if (username.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        username.setError("Please enter your username");
                    } else if (mailid.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        mailid.setError("Please enter your e-mail id");
                    } else if (password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        password.setError("Please enter your password");
                    } else if (confirmpassword.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        confirmpassword.setError("Please re-enter your password");
                    }
                    if(!password.equals(confirmpassword))
                    {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(RegistrationPage.this);
                        d.setTitle("Passwords do not match");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(RegistrationPage.this);
                        tv.setText("Please re-enter the passwords");
                        d.setContentView(tv);

                    }

                    db.insertRecord(firstname.getText().toString(),middlename.getText().toString(),lastname.getText().toString(),dob.getText().toString(),country.getText().toString(),username.getText().toString(),mailid.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(),confirmpassword.getText().toString());
                    Log.i("RegistrationPage","Records are inserted");
                    Intent profile_intent = new Intent(RegistrationPage.this,Profile_view.class);
                    startActivity(profile_intent);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.registration_page, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }

**Edit StackTrace :**

     12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.example.signup.RegistrationPage$1.onClick(RegistrationPage.java:26)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    12-03 16:33:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-03 16:33:18.405: I/Process(707): Sending signal. PID: 707 SIG: 9
```

When i give all the details and submit, I am getting the exception and also it is to be noted that i am just inserting the data into the database and then call an `intent.insert(...)` method is implemented in another class.

```
     The logcat says null pointer exception in line 26 which is the line where i verify the if condition for firstname.getText().toString().length()==0 .

  Help me as I am new to programming and android.
```

Comment: add complete code or let us know which part of the code is 45th line

Comment: @San There is null value passing in one of your detail. Please the code of `line45`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer: use

`firstname.isEmpty()` instead of

`firstname.getText().toString().length() == 0`

The code is so long to verify. Then update the line num 45

My guess is : `db` is not opened and therefore `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `EditText` variables in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`:

```
firstname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_of_firstname_edittext);
middlename = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I never thought that i might do such a silly mistake. It worked in the sense that it is not throwing the same error but it says classcastexception while trying to launch the activity. Any idea on this part. Thanks for taking the effort.

Comment: @San First check that the layout XML elements have the same types you're trying to cast the result of `findViewById(R.id.something)` to. Also, if you recently edited your resources, resource ids may be out of sync. In that case, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287855/unable-to-connect-sqlitedatabase-in-android cause i have been sitting on it from a long time.